# Access one of the multiple result parameters return by a function in go

Tags: go

Here's the sample code (from tour.golang.org),

```
package main    

import "fmt"

func split(sum int) (x, y int) {
    x = sum * 4 / 9
    y = sum - x
    return
}

func main() {
    x, _ := split(17)
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

I would like to know if it is possible to shorten the main function to just a single line. Logically there should be a way (might not look very elegant in this case though) to access only first result parameter returned from function and print it.

Answer (score 0):

`fmt.Println` is a variadic function, so you can just pass the split function as a parameter:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(split(17))
}
```

see it working in full here: http://play.golang.org/p/c1zkFVMe11

Comment: I want to print just the value of x, as shown in my snippet. Not a best example though, but you get the point.

Comment: @aamir ahh - sorry I misunderstood.  If you need to massage the output of the function, you probably will need multiple lines.  You could also make a function which ingests the output of `split` and then prints it as you want...but that would be even more lines.

Comment: I was just curious if there's a way, maybe like split(17)[0] to retrieve first element, not that I want to reduce the number of lines actually. Thanks for trying anyway!

Comment: That's not possible, @aamir. You can chain `split` into another function like @dethtron5000 did, but there's no syntatic sugar to retrieve only one of the elements.